# How do I animate zoom in and out in a NSScrollView so that it is smooth?

Tags: zooming, nsscrollview

Below are the functions I am using to set the new size of the scroll views documentView, however I can't figure out how to combine the frame size change with the change in the scroll position.  If I apply animation to things as they are the size gets changes and the image moves relative to the bottom left corner and then the image gets scrolled back into position.  How do I combined the animation such that the size change and the scroll position change together - or any other way to achieve a smooth zoom in/out.

```
func zoomIn(zoomFactor: CGFloat = zoomFactor){

        guard let docView = self.docView, let scrollView = self.scrollView else {
            return
        }

        let visible = scrollView.documentVisibleRect
        let newrect = NSInsetRect(visible, NSWidth(visible)*(1 - 1/zoomFactor)/2.0, NSHeight(visible)*(1 - 1/zoomFactor)/2.0);
        let frame = docView.frame

        self.execZoom(docView: docView,
                      size:CGSize(width: zoomFactor, height: zoomFactor),
                      frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width * zoomFactor, height: frame.size.height * zoomFactor),
                      origin:newrect.origin)

    }
    func zoomOut(zoomFactor: CGFloat = zoomFactor){
        guard let docView = self.docView, let scrollView = self.scrollView else {
            return
        }
        let visible = scrollView.documentVisibleRect
        let newrect = NSOffsetRect(visible, -NSWidth(visible)*(zoomFactor - 1)/2.0, -NSHeight(visible)*(zoomFactor - 1)/2.0)

        let frame = docView.frame

        self.execZoom(docView: docView,
                      size: CGSize(width: 1/zoomFactor, height: 1/zoomFactor),
                      frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width / zoomFactor, height: frame.size.height / zoomFactor),
                      origin: newrect.origin)
    }
    func execZoom(docView: NSView, size: CGSize, frame: CGRect, origin: CGPoint){

            docView.scaleUnitSquare(to: size)

            docView.frame = frame

            docView.scroll(origin)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to use the generic 'animated'.

From the documentation:
*To animate the magnification, use the object's animator. The default value is 1.0.*
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollview/1403497-magnification?language=objc)

What does that mean 'use the object's animator'?

Rather than:

```
self.scrollView.setMagnification(magnification, centeredAt: point)
```

Call on it's animator:

```
self.scrollView.animator().setMagnification(magnification, centeredAt: point)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK just throw all that away and do this... crazy fast, smooth and all the underlying CALayers with images and draggable CALayers that render with their own draw() methods seems to scale in vector format - no pixelation of fonts, lines or images.

```
   override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {

        guard event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
            return
        }

        let dy = event.deltaY
        if dy != 0.0 {

            let magnification = self.scrollView.magnification + dy/30
            let point = self.scrollView.contentView.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)

            self.scrollView.setMagnification(magnification, centeredAt: point)
        }
    }
```